# JWTClaimsSet.Builder() and JSONObject - Object inside Verifiable Presentation JWT

Tags: jwt, openid, nimbus-jose-jwt

I've to create a JWTClaim which has inside a property with a JSON:

```
exampleClaimJson = {
     "nonce":"13234-3234345-34454",
}
```

In Java I'm building it like this:

```
JSONObject exampleClaimJson = new JSONObject();
didJson.put("nonce","13234-3234345-34454");

JWTClaimsSet claimsSet = new JWTClaimsSet.Builder()
    .subject(did)
    .claim("exampleJson", exampleClaimJson)
    .build()
```

But then inside the JWT the "exampleJson" claim is represented like this:

```
{
     ...
     "exampleJson": {
          "map": {
                  "nonce":"13234-3234345-34454"
          }
     }
}
```

On the other hand if I use

```
.claim("exampleJson", exampleClaimJson.toString())
```

Then it turns into:

```
{
     ...
     "exampleJson": "{\"nonce\":\"13234-3234345-34454\"}"
}
```

To me none of those look ok, in particular because the structure of the Claim will be verified and must be just a JSON, not with map declarations and not a simple string.

Does anyone know if this is the correct approach in Java? I'm looking at this [Building JSON Web Token using JSONObject and JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32626125/building-json-web-token-using-jsonobject-and-jsonarray) (from 2015 though..) - what's the difference between the minidev and the java json objects? Is it a normal practice to include different JSON libraries for Java projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks right - perhaps there is some kind of library incompatibility? To work with object claims, see the [nimbus tests](https://github.com/felx/nimbus-jose-jwt/blob/master/src/test/java/com/nimbusds/jwt/JWTClaimsSetTest.java#L758). Here is some working code:

```java
var verifiablePresentationJson = new JSONObject()
verifiablePresentationJson.put("nonce", "13234-3234345-34454")

val did = "did:example:user123"
val claimsSet = new JWTClaimsSet.Builder()
    .subject(did)
    .claim("verifiablePresentationJson", verifiablePresentationJson)
    .build()
System.out.println(claimsSet.toString())
```

Note that you should be using the following class and not some other implementation:

```
net.minidev.json.JSONObject
```

Do so by adding this dependency, in the same way as the nimbus project does:

```
implementation("net.minidev:json-smart:2.5.0")
```

Comment: Thanks, yea, my error was that I was not using the net.minidev.json.JSONObject!